# Out of bounds array exeption

Tags: java

Im trying to complete an investigation of the knights tour on bigger chess boards. I have designed this code but will not work past 8x8 and I need it to go to 20x20

```
class KnightTour {
static int N = 8;
static boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int sol[][]) {
    return (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 &&
            y < N && sol[x][y] == -1);
}
static void printSolution(int sol[][]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            System.out.print(sol[x][y] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static boolean solveKT() {
    int sol[][] = new int[18][18];
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            sol[x][y] = -1;
    int xMove[] = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};
    int yMove[] = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
    sol[0][0] = 0;
    if (!solveKTUtil(0, 0, 1, sol, xMove, yMove)) {
        System.out.println("Solution does not exist");
        return false;
    } else
        printSolution(sol);
    return true;
}
static boolean solveKTUtil(int x, int y, int movei,
                           int sol[][], int xMove[],
                           int yMove[]) {
    int k, next_x, next_y;
    if (movei == N * N)
        return true;
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        next_x = x + xMove[k];
        next_y = y + yMove[k];
        if (isSafe(next_x, next_y, sol)) {
            sol[next_x][next_y] = movei;
            if (solveKTUtil(next_x, next_y, movei + 1, sol, xMove, yMove))
                return true;
            else
                sol[next_x][next_y] = -1;// backtracking
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    solveKT();
}
```

}

It should display the number move on the tile without repeating a single tile.

This is the output on 8x8:

0 59 38 33 30 17 8 63 
37 34 31 60 9 62 29 16 
58 1 36 39 32 27 18 7 
35 48 41 26 61 10 15 28 
42 57 2 49 40 23 6 19 
47 50 45 54 25 20 11 14 
56 43 52 3 22 13 24 5 
51 46 55 44 53 4 21 12

Here is what I tried:

```
class KnightTour {
static int N = 20;
static boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int sol[][]) {
    return (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 &&
            y < N && sol[x][y] == -1);
}
static void printSolution(int sol[][]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            System.out.print(sol[x][y] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static boolean solveKT() {
    int sol[][] = new int[20][20];
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            sol[x][y] = -1;
    int xMove[] = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};
    int yMove[] = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
    sol[0][0] = 0;
    if (!solveKTUtil(0, 0, 1, sol, xMove, yMove)) {
        System.out.println("Solution does not exist");
        return false;
    } else
        printSolution(sol);
    return true;
}
static boolean solveKTUtil(int x, int y, int movei,
                           int sol[][], int xMove[],
                           int yMove[]) {
    int k, next_x, next_y;
    if (movei == N * N)
        return true;
    for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
        next_x = x + xMove[k];
        next_y = y + yMove[k];
        if (isSafe(next_x, next_y, sol)) {
            sol[next_x][next_y] = movei;
            if (solveKTUtil(next_x, next_y, movei + 1, sol, xMove, yMove))
                return true;
            else
                sol[next_x][next_y] = -1;// backtracking
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    solveKT();
}
```

}

Comment: Please add stack trace (error message) to the question

Comment: Here is what I tried:

Comment: It's time to try using a debugger

Comment: It may not be the only issue, but one place is that you declare the arrays 'xMove' and 'yMove' to have 8 elements then you try to access up to element 19 in your loop for 'solveKTUtil'. As Hovercraft said, you're best going through it step by step. Use a debugger, add some logging statements and check the line reported in your stack trace each time